# Convert openvswitch types to little endian

Tags: c, endianness, openvswitch

In Open vSwitch 2.4.0 implementation, we do have the following:

```
#ifdef __CHECKER__
#define OVS_BITWISE __attribute__((bitwise))
#define OVS_FORCE __attribute__((force))
#else
#define OVS_BITWISE
#define OVS_FORCE
#endif

/* The ovs_be<N> types indicate that an object is in big-endian, not
 * native-endian, byte order.  They are otherwise equivalent to uint<N>_t. */

typedef uint16_t OVS_BITWISE ovs_be16;
typedef struct {
    ovs_be16 hi, lo;
} ovs_16aligned_be32;
```

I have the following variables:

```
ovs_16aligned_be32 srcIP;
ovs_be16 srcPort ;
```

How can I convert `srcIP` into a `xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt` and the `srcPort` into a little-endian `uint16_t` ?

Answer (score 1):

there are already the functions:

```
htonl()
htons()
ntohl()
ntohs()
```

Which are prototyped in

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

If I understand your question correctly, these functions will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I do not know what is openvswitch but I think this should work:

```
ovs_16aligned_be32 ovs_16aligned_be32_to_littleEndian(ovs_16aligned_be32 a) {
    ovs_16aligned_be32 b.high = ovs_be16_toLittleEndian(a.low);
    b.low = ovs_be16_toLittleEndian(a.high);
    return b;
}

ovs_be16 ovs_be16_toLittleEndian(ovs_be16 srcPort a) {
   ovs_be16 srcPort b = (a >> 8) & 0x00ff;
   b |= a << 8;

   return b;
}
```